# Get the symmetrical signal

Tags: matlab

Given a signal `x(t)`, we need to find the symmetrical with respect to the Y-axis signal, `x(-t)`

If it's helpful to you, here's how my code works thus far:

```
t = [-5:0.01:5];
wt = (t>=0)&(t<=1);
r = @(t) t/5;
x = r(t).*wt;
%reflection - HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK, basically looking for v(t) = x(-t)
%Shift by 2
y = v(t-2);
%The rest of the program - printing plots basically
```

I have tried using these:

- `v = x(t(1:end));`
- `v = x(t(end:-1:1));`
- `v = x(fliplr(t));`

But it's not correct, since I get the error `Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.` as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was defining a `reflect` function as follows:

```
function val = reflect(t)
    val = -t;
end
```

And then using it with the shifting function in order to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that you consider something like this:

```
x=signal;   % with length 2*N+1 and symmetric 
t= -N:N;
```

now, consider you want the value of index -2.

```
x(find(t==-2))
```

For ramp signal as an instance:

```
signal=[r(end:-1:1) 0 r]
```

with this assumption that r is a row-base vector and N length.

Comment: My signal is not symmetric though, it's (as indicated by the initial part of the code) basically the ramp function (r) for t in [0,1]

Comment: Later in my code I will have to 'reflect' the signal x(t) shifted by 2 units as well, but given a solution for x(t), that should be easy to implement.

Comment: You can create your symmtletric signal and put it in Signal variable with virtual point as symmetric point.

Comment: What do you mean by `with virtual point as symmetric point` ?

Comment: Consider that you want to create symmetric signal with respect to y=0 axis, then I called '0' as virtual point since you can change it by above formulation.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You should first define the signal function and *then* sampling it, not the other way round.

For instance, I here define a signal `s(t)` which is a windowed ramp:

```
s = @(t) t.*((t>=0)&(t<=1))
```

Then, I can find the samples for the signal and its symmetrical:

```
t = -5:0.01:5;
plot(t,s(t),t,s(-t))
```

Comment: What does `@` do in this case? I'm afraid I'm fairly new to matlab and haven't come across this statement before

Comment: @Zap It defines an [anonymous function](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and `s` is a [function handle](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html). You can also use the usual functions indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Given any sampled signal in an arbitrary time interval:

```
t = [-5.003:0.01:10];
x = randn(size(t));
```

You can reflect `x` around `t=0` with:

```
t = -flip(t);
x = flip(x);
```

Note that in the example above, `t=0` is not sampled. This is not necessary for this method.